# Dynamic url parameters and UI Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to figure out how I can get query parameters in the url using UI Router and AngularJS UI Bootstrap Typeahead fully working.

I have it working (well... kind of). What happens is that you have to search twice, once puts the query in the url and twice gives you results. Not ideal.

After doing some more searching and reading, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24589340/3125823) and it seems that using an $http service would be a good way to go. However, I'm only using **ONE** controller with 2 views. Will that still work?

**UPDATE**

The answer in the link provides an answer based on having 2 controllers, whereas I only have one controller.

So my question(s) is would using an $http service to store my query in enable me to put the query parameter in the url using UI Router and AngularJS UI Bootstrap Typeahead? Is this SOLEY a UI Router issue or is UI Bootstrap Typeahead play a role in this?

Code:
In my controller I initialize the relevant code like this:

```
$scope.searchTerms = $stateParams.searchTerms || '';
```

and use $state.go in my search function like this:

```
$state.go('search', {q: $scope.searchTerms});
```

It works like I said, but only after submitting the search query twice. Trying to figure how to get it working *normally*.

Comment: i don't get your problem. can you paste code of what you already done and which part don't work

Comment: @AlainIb please check the UPDATE above